# Q: How to fix the missing dependancies in pyzbar

Tags: python-3.x, dll, anaconda, dependencies, zbar

I am currently using spyder via anaconda with python 3.8.5 on windows 10 and I am trying to use the pyzbar package to make a barcode reader. When I try to run the script I get this error message when trying to run `from pyzbar.pyzbar import decode` and `from pyzbar import pyzbar`:

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\norinhan\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyzbar\zbar_library.py", line 58, in load
    dependencies, libzbar = load_objects(Path(''))

  File "C:\Users\norinhan\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyzbar\zbar_library.py", line 50, in load_objects
    deps = [

  File "C:\Users\norinhan\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyzbar\zbar_library.py", line 51, in <listcomp>
    cdll.LoadLibrary(str(directory.joinpath(dep)))

  File "C:\Users\norinhan\Anaconda3\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 459, in LoadLibrary
    return self._dlltype(name)

  File "C:\Users\norinhan\Anaconda3\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 381, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)

FileNotFoundError: Could not find module 'libiconv.dll' (or one of its dependencies). Try using the full path with constructor syntax.


During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-1-95ae0761f4b5>", line 1, in <module>
    from pyzbar.pyzbar import decode

  File "C:\Users\norinhan\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyzbar\pyzbar.py", line 7, in <module>
    from .wrapper import (

  File "C:\Users\norinhan\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyzbar\wrapper.py", line 139, in <module>
    zbar_version = zbar_function(

  File "C:\Users\norinhan\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyzbar\wrapper.py", line 136, in zbar_function
    return prototype((fname, load_libzbar()))

  File "C:\Users\norinhan\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyzbar\wrapper.py", line 115, in load_libzbar
    libzbar, dependencies = zbar_library.load()

  File "C:\Users\norinhan\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyzbar\zbar_library.py", line 60, in load
    dependencies, libzbar = load_objects(Path(__file__).parent)

  File "C:\Users\norinhan\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyzbar\zbar_library.py", line 50, in load_objects
    deps = [

  File "C:\Users\norinhan\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyzbar\zbar_library.py", line 51, in <listcomp>
    cdll.LoadLibrary(str(directory.joinpath(dep)))

  File "C:\Users\norinhan\Anaconda3\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 459, in LoadLibrary
    return self._dlltype(name)

  File "C:\Users\norinhan\Anaconda3\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 381, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)

FileNotFoundError: Could not find module 'C:\Users\norinhan\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyzbar\libiconv.dll' (or one of its dependencies). Try using the full path with constructor syntax.
```

When trying to run just `import pyzbar` it will compile, but it will not be able to access any of the function. When I try I get this message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-3-26272af93b8a>", line 1, in <module>
    pyzbar.pyzbar.decode()

AttributeError: module 'pyzbar' has no attribute 'pyzbar'
```

I have looked up the [documentation for pyzbar on github](https://github.com/NaturalHistoryMuseum/pyzbar) which states "The zbar DLLs are included with the Windows Python wheels", but have not found this anywhere. The closest to "Windows Python wheels" I have found is [the wheel package](https://pythonwheels.com/) which does not contain any information about pyzbar.

Any advice on how to fix this?

Answer (score 3):

Visit https://pypi.org/project/pyzbar/#files to download pyzbar-0.1.8-py2.py3-none-win_amd64.whl.

[image]

You can find all the DLL files inside the wheel package.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I have just encountered this problem.
If your OS & python are x64 version, it's just because of lack of vc 2013 x64 runtime.

You can find [`Visual C++ Redistributable Packages for Visual Studio 2013` here](https://www.microsoft.com/zh-cn/download/confirmation.aspx?id=40784)

download & install.

Comment: It is already installed for me though and I'm getting the same error

Answer (score 0):

I was facing similar issue just installed Visual
C++ 64 bit version on my computer and restarted. Choose between    vcredist_x86.exe or vcredist_x64.exe based on your machine.

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=40784. Hope this solves your issue as well.

Answer (score 0):

Please install
Windows error message
If you see an ugly ImportError when importing pyzbar on Windows you will most likely need the Visual C++ Redistributable Packages for Visual Studio 2013. **Install vcredist_x64.exe** if using 64-bit Python, vcredist_x86.exe if using 32-bit Python.

Click on below link... (Go to bootom of the appeared web page) and get it installed...

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/windows/latest-supported-vc-redist?view=msvc-170